# How do these refer to Harrison Ford and Patrick Stewart?

Tags: actors

I just got an ad/email from ThinkGeek which says,

> Today marks the birth of two of our favorite actors: one a scruffy-lookin' archaeologist with a 4-year life span and the other a cowboy crooner. That's right. Happy birthday to both Harrison Ford and Sir Patrick Stewart.

On the Harrison Ford side, I get that *scruffy-lookin'* refers to Leia's famous "scruffy-looking nerf-herder" line from ESB, and *archeologist* refers to Indiana Jones, but *4-year life span* has me stumped.

On the Patrick Stewart side, I have absolutely no idea what *cowboy crooner* has to do with anything I've seen Captain Picard/Professor X do.

<sub>(With my luck, the missing references will turn out to have nothing to do with science fiction or fantasy, and this'll get moved to Movies & TV, where I don't have an account... well, here goes nothing, anyway.)</sub>

Comment: The four year lifespan refers to Harrison Ford's role as Rick Deckard in Blade Runner and the, spoilers, debate over whether or not he is a Replicant.

Comment: The cowboy crooner refers to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK9dlmYvB-Y) Patrick Stewart made.

Comment: @Praxis Since even having seen *Star Wars* evidently isn't ... ;-)

Comment: Picard is, of course, [something of an archeology enthusiast](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Captain%27s_Holiday_(episode)) himself. I don’t recall him ever looking scruffy though.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - [Scruffy-looking Picard](http://i.imgur.com/DIp8dEX.gif)

Comment: @Valorum: scruffy? He hasn’t a single strap out of place!

Comment: I always thought the line was "scruffy-looking nerve-hurter."

Comment: @Phyneas Why don't you turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Cowboy Crooner

Patrick Stewart recently released a (spoof) album of Cowboy and Western songs.

From the [goodnewsnetwork website](http://www.goodnewsnetwork.org/patrick-stewart-cowboy-songs/):

> Billed in the video as “England’s premier cowboy singer,” Stewart
>   cracks a whip and dances in boots and chaps as he croons while selling
>   his collection of five tunes, like the theme from “Rawhide,” “Buttons
>   and Bows,” and “South of the Border.”
>
> Stewart put together the parody video and recorded a real five-song CD
>   as part of a charity fundraiser for the International Rescue Committee
>   which helps refugees and families struggling through crises.

### 4-year lifespan

As you can see from the answer that @Praxis' has posted below, it has recently(ish) been confirmed that Deckard, the main character in Blade Runner was indeed a replicant, and hence only has a lifespan of four years.

> I knew it on the roof that night. **We were brothers, Roy Batty and I!
>   Combat models of the highest order.** We had fought in wars not yet
>   dreamed of... in vast nightmares still unnamed. We were the new
>   people... Roy and me and Rachael! We were made for this world. It was
>   ours!
>
> <sub><sup>[Blade Runner's Original Ending: Yes, Deckard's A Replicant](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5181048/blade-runners-original-ending-yes-deckards-a-replicant)</sup></sub>

Comment: We posted within 30 seconds of each other, you with Stewart and me with Ford.  I thought about editing my answer to include Stewart but decided not to in deference to your answer which already covers it.  I figured that the nice thing to do was not to try to supplant your answer.  Now you've gone ahead and added in the 4-year lifespan into yours.  Great. :-P

Comment: can't... stop... laughing... Oh, gods, that video! It's somehow made even funnier by the fact that it turns out Captain Picard has a lovely singing voice. Has he been taking lessons from his new wife?

Comment: Note that you're quoting a draft of the script from before the second writer even got involved. Movie plot points can always change drastically between draft-scripts and what ends up on screen. In the case of *Blade Runner*, even "what ends up on screen" isn't so simple; there are deleted scenes and (as noted by the other answer) "word of God" that confirm Deckard is a replicant, but the various full cuts of the film leave varying degrees of ambiguity about the issue, and I think that's intentional.

Comment: So the reference is certainly the correct one, but I think "recently(ish) been confirmed)" is a little strong.

Comment: @KyleStrand - There are other answers on the site that go into dramatically more detail than either of the answers here. Clearly the advert is referring to Deckard being a replicant. Demonstrating that is really beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Martha I *think* there was at least one episode of ST:NG that featured Stewart singing - I don't think this is a new found talent.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer should dive into the question of whether or not Deckard is or is not a replicant, though I think it would be an improvement for it to simply *acknowledge that that's even a question*. But regardless of whether or not you want to acknowledge that ambiguity, the point that you've cited a *draft script*, and that draft scripts *mean nothing*, remains; it would be much better to quote a relevant from the movie itself about the four-year lifespan and, separately, to quote Ridley Scott stating that Deckard is a replicant.

Comment: @Valorum : I believe your behaviour on this particular post has been deplorable and, if memory serves, this exact behaviour on your part is the reason we lost a well-respected, high-rep user last year.  If you had pinged me below my answer before you updated yours (with the same source material, no less) I would have said, "Sure, go for it".  If you had acted unilaterally, but had put something such as, "As already pointed out by Praxis' in his answer..." I would have also been perfectly fine.  If you had taken my concern in my original comment above seriously, I may also have been fine.

Comment: @Valorum : Better.  (Note: I have no downvote to reverse, just an upvote to give you. +1)

Comment: Never understood how, if Deckard was a replicant, Pris (a leisure model) manages to beat seven bells of cr@p out of him. As, in fact, does every other replicant he meets. I can;t remember the original book but in the film, there is far more evidence for him NOT being a replicant than for him being one.

Comment: @SteveIves The book gives no indication that Deckard might be a replicant.

Answer (score 30):

Replicants in *Blade Runner* have a 4-year life span:

The "4-year lifespan" with regards to Harrison Ford refers to a **long-running rumour / belief that Ford's character Deckard, a specialist in replicant termination, might actually be a replicant himself.**

For more info, read here:

- [*Blade Runner*'s Original Ending: Yes, Deckard's a Replicant!](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5181048/blade-runners-original-ending-yes-deckards-a-replicant)

In December 2014, Director Ridley Scott finally weighed in on the issue:

> **“He is definitely a replicant,”** Scott says.

([Source](http://comicbook.com/2014/12/18/ridley-scott-answers-whether-deckard-is-a-replicant-in-blade-run/))

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't matter what Ridley Scott says. If it's not confirmed within the movie itself then it is still open to interpretation. Early drafts of the script are irrelevant, other than for general interest about how the story evolved - the "final" story is what's in the movie. Blade Runner doesn't need after-the-fact Lucas-style rewrites...